# Comparing two exponential random variable and expected values

Tags: probability, statistics, conditional-expectation, exponential-distribution

I have two independent exponential r.v. X and Y with rates $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$. It is known that $\lambda_1 < \lambda_2$. I'm curios about the followings

- $E[X| X<Y]$
- $E[Y| X<Y]$ (I guess = $E[Y]$)
- $E[(X-Y)| X<Y]$

What I found:

$f_{X,Y}(x,y) = \lambda_1\lambda_2 e^{-\lambda_1x - \lambda_2y}$ , since X and Y are independent.

$P\{X<Y\} = \int_0^\infty dx \int_x^\infty f_{X,Y}(x,y)$

I'm not sure whether

$E[X| X<Y] = \int_0^\infty xdx \int_x^\infty f_{X,Y}(x,y)$

If you can help me on this, I will be appreciated.

Comment: Are $X$ and $Y$ independent?

Comment: Please add some [context](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) to your question.

Comment: @JackM yes they are independent, sorry for missing it

Comment: By definition, $E[X\mid X<Y]=\frac{1}{P(X<Y)}E[XI_{X<Y}]$ where $I$ is an indicator variable. After finding the first two, the third one is just $E[X\mid X<Y]-E[Y\mid X<Y]$ by linearity.

Comment: @StubbornAtom thanks, but still no idea how to find $E[XI_{X<Y}]$

Comment: Use [LOTUS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_unconscious_statistician) for finding the expectation.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the solution, but it is complicated than I thought.

$X$ and $Y$ are independent exponential r.v. with $\lambda$ and $\mu$.

Start with the easy one:

$$ E[Y|Y>X] = \int_0^\infty E[Y|Y>x]f_X(x)dx$$
$$ E[Y|Y>x] = \int_0^\infty y f_{Y|Y>x}(y)dy = \int_0^\infty \frac{yf_Y(y)I_{Y>x}}{P(Y>x)}dy$$
$$=\int_x^\infty \frac{y\mu e^{-\mu y}}{e^{-\mu x}}dy = E[Y] + x = \frac{1}{\mu} + x$$ --> Because of the memoryless property.

Back to the first equation.

$$E[Y|Y>X] =\int_0^\infty E[Y|Y>x]f_X(x)dx = \int_0^\infty \bigl( \frac{1}{\mu} + x\bigl) \lambda e^{-\lambda x} dx = \frac{1}{\mu} + \frac{1}{\lambda}$$

Note that it is same thing as $E[Y| Y>X] = \int_0^\infty dx \int_x^\infty y f_{X,Y}(x,y) dy$

Others will come...

Comment: If $X$ and $Y$ have different rate parameters, they're not identically distributed.

Comment: You are right ✋